# DataTables Editor - internationalisation

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

In JQuery DataTable they can Add refrence to Olanguage to be in file

```js
"oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": "media/language/de_DE.txt"
        }
```

[link]http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/language_file.html

there is Extra Plugin called Editor 
they add Directly language refrence to the column

```js
"i18n": {
            "create": {
                "button": "Nouveau",
                "title":  "Créer nouvelle entrée",
                "submit": "Créer"
            },
            "edit": {
                "button": "Modifier",
                "title":  "Modifier entrée",
                "submit": "Actualiser"
            },
            "remove": {
                "button": "Supprimer",
                "title":  "Supprimer",
                "submit": "Supprimer",
                "confirm": {
                    "_": "Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer %d lignes?",
                    "1": "Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer 1 ligne?"
                }
            },
            "error": {
                "system": "Une erreur s’est produite, contacter l’administrateur système"
            }
```

http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/i18n.html

Ineed to Put i18n in text file like DataTable

Answer (score 0):

Make your own JS language file, let's call it `editor.i18n.fr.js`.
Have it contain your i18n data in a global variable say like:

```
var DTE_i18n = {
        "create": {
            "button": "Nouveau",
            "title":  "Créer nouvelle entrée",
            "submit": "Créer"
        },
        "edit": {
            "button": "Modifier",
            "title":  "Modifier entrée",
            "submit": "Actualiser"
        },
        "remove": {
            "button": "Supprimer",
            "title":  "Supprimer",
            "submit": "Supprimer",
            "confirm": {
                "_": "Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer %d lignes?",
                "1": "Etes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer 1 ligne?"
            }
        },
        "error": {
            "system": "Une erreur s’est produite, contacter l’administrateur système"
        }
}
```

Link to it in your main html file:

```
<script src="js/editor.i18n.fr.js"></script>
```

Then in you editor init reference it in your i18n property:

```
var editor_create = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: 'ajax/table.users.php',
    table: '#users',
    fields: [
        {
            "label": "user :",
            "name": "user"
        },
        {
            "label": "pass :",
            "name": "pass"
        }
    ],
    i18n: DTE_i18n
} );
```